# Nodered boilerplate and Analytics for Apache Hadoop binding issue

Tags: hadoop, ibm-cloud, node-red, analytics-for-hadoop, analytics-for-apache-hdp

I have created the nodered boilerplate and i have binded the Analytics for Apache Hadoop service.
So it clearly appears as a binded service into the dashboard.
[image]

But when I launch the Nodered app and add a HDFS node, I get the following message:
"Unbounded Service: Big Insights service not bound. This node wont work"

Any idea of what i am doing wrong? It used to work well for me a few weeks ago.

Comment: Have you restarted the Node-RED app since binding the service? The vcap data will only get updated after a restart.

Comment: yes, I did restart it. The issue must be that I need to use the BigI for Apache Hadoop as Jeff is suggesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to attach the [BigInsights for Apache Hadoop service](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/biginsights-for-apache-hadoop/) service to your app.

Please attach the service and restage/restage your app.